# Is there an option to get per-sentence processing time from the Stanford Parser?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm currently parsing Arabic text using the following command:

```
java -mx1500m edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser \
  -cp "$scriptdir/*:" -sentences newline -outputFormat "penn,wordsAndTags" \
  edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/arabicFactored.ser.gz $FILE
```

This outputs tokens, tags, and parse trees, plus a global overview on the processing speed similar to this output:

```
Parsed 280 words in 10 sentences (1.95 wds/sec; 0.07 sents/sec).
```

Is there an option or command line switch to trigger output of processing time on a *per-sentence* level? Or would I have to add that to the code myself?

Haven't found such an option neither in the FAQ nor on the Stanford NLP website, so I'd appreciate if someone could clarify on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, at present there isn't.  You'd need to add the code yourself.

Comment: There is such option in documentation (http://tides.umiacs.umd.edu/webtrec/stanfordParser/javadoc/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/lexparser/LexicalizedParser.html#main%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) and in faq (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#e). Does it work already?